# FileInfo unable to find specified file exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have what could be an unusual problem. My problem is that I have a collection of file paths which contain the filenames too. As the code loops round the collection it takes the string and creates a FileInfo object. With this object it then uses the MoveTo method to move the file to another location.

This all works well until it reaches a file with a zero length and says it cannot find the file. If I take this file and create a FileInfo object in a different application it works regardless of size. Does anyone know about what is causing this and how to solve it? Relevant code snippet below

```
IList<string> files = new List<string >();
files.add(file1);
files.add(file2);

foreach (string filepath in files) 
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo (filepath);
    string newlocation = Path.Combine(dest, file.name);

    file.MoveTo (newlocation); //exception thrown here on zero length 
}
```

Comment: FileInfo wont throw an exception for a non existent path. you need to use `Exists` first before trying to perform any action that relies on the file existing.

Comment: Missing the point. The exists but it says that it does not. If you read my note I said that I wrote a test to check that it does move the file and it does. Exist is not the point on this. The question is why is it doing this

Comment: Just to troubleshoot does the same happen if you use `File.Move`

Comment: And also. event with a zero length `Exists` returns `true`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `file.Refresh()` before `file.MoveTo(...)`.

Read **Remarks** in this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.exists.aspx

Comment: I did notice this earlier and I tried this in between creating a new fileinfo object and calling moveto and this made no difference

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
       System.IO.File.Move(Sourcefile, DestinationFile);
```

More details:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Issue is just the same makes no difference

Comment: Did you check your  source and destination path correctly ?

Comment: Yes, because the path is the same for other files and they work.